# PHP Buffer read

Tags: php, json, sql-server

I have a quandary. I need to use PHP to read a SQL result. The field is coming back as "*application/x-gzip; charset=binary*". I've been stuck on this for a while.

Recently, I was able to expand the string data using Node-Red, but that is not a production option.

In Node Red, I query the database and get back this:

```
"[{"ClientNumber":12,"ClientName":"Jim's Test account",
"Name":"10650 - Inbound Webhook / MergeComm",
"blockid":194194,
"Script":{"type":"Buffer","data":[31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,237,93,9,115,27,71,174,238,159,194,242,86,189,218,87,9,99,146,51,156,35,111,55,91,242,21,43,27,217,94,203,118,142,221,148,119,56,28,250,136,44,41,146,124,37,241,127,127,192,7,244,28,228,240,26,146,195,17....
```

From there I pull the "script" object and create a buffer:

```
var bufferOriginal = msg.payload; //get payload
let json = (JSON.parse(bufferOriginal));
let script = Buffer.from(json[0].Script);
msg.payload = script;
return msg;
```

Once the buffer is read/streamed in, it is GZipped where the "Script" is now human readable (either XML or JSON)

THAT side works. However, when I query the database via PHP and try to JSON_ENCODE results, I get a high level of bytes and non-printable characters.

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
array(5) {
["ClientNumber"]=>
string(2) "12"
["ClientName"]=>
string(32) " - Jim's Test account"
["Name"]=>
string(35) "10650 - Inbound Webhook / MergeComm"
["blockid"]=>
string(6) "194194"
["Script"]=>
string(4096) ""�
```

And when I try to JSON_ENCODE either the ROW OR just the field, it returns bool(false), but does not throw an error.

***Note**, if I leave that column OUT of the query, it encodes just fine*

The issue, I am presuming is that NODE (Node-Red) understands the "application/x-gzip; charset=binary" data stream and PHP does not. I believe if I can get PHP to read that stream into Byte code or Hex or the Decimal equivalent, I could move forward.

How can I correctly read in the column?

Comment: I'm not clear what's going on here. PHP includes drivers for most popular SQL database servers, including SQL Server that you've tagged. Why are you not using those? FWIW, PHP can decode GZIP data - see [gzdecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php)

Comment: Why is Node-RED not a valid solution

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. The first examples were what I was able to get from Node Red (which is not an option as it has not been vetted within our IT team for security). 

The last code snippet is the result from using PHP  and we use it for a lot of our back end and middle ware processes. We make several thousand SQL calls per day using PHP. 

The issue is this one field type. The data type is not one I've worked with in the past. The vendor used it to stored XML code that is compressed. I am looking to uncompress it to make it viewable/searchable.